# How to update invalid commit in main git repository due to git submodule rewrites history?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The situation is like this

A main git repository depends on a git submodule. Along the development process on main repository, a developer commits and associates such commit with changes happening in git submodule. But later, that git submodule did some rebase, and force-push. Thus it rewrites the history making those commits referenced from the main git repository invalid.

**Example scenario**:

(Main project has the following git submodule)

```
$ git submodule status
xxxxxx... src/myGitSubmoduleProject (....)
```

(`myGitSubmoduleProject` has some changes)

```
$ cd src/myGitSubmoduleProject
$ git add -u .
$ git commit -m "modified certain source file"
$ git push origin <certain-branch>
```

(back to main git repo to commit the change associating with recent git submodule changes)

```
$ cd ../../
$ git add local-file
$ git add src/myGitSubmoduleProject # (comment: add changes from git submodule)
$ git commit -m "implement new feature"
$ git push origin <certain-branch>
```

(time progresses on...)

(`myGitSubmoduleProject` rebases and forces-push, thus rewrites history

```
$ cd src/myGitSubmoduleProject
$ git rebase -i <certain-commit-hash> # (comment: let's say it invalidates commit(s) referenced from main repository)
$ ... (interact with rebasing) ...
$ git push origin <certain-branch> --force-with-lease
```

(now main git repository has reference to invalid commits of git submodule)

The question is how to update invalidated commits as referenced from main git repository to the updated ones from git submodule with git command line?

Comment: Your main repository is screwed. You have to rewrite its history as well.

Comment: @j6t Do you mean something like on main git repository, do interactive rebase to fix those specific commits pointing to updated commits from git submodule?

Comment: Yes. The submodule commit that is referenced by the main repository will be garbage collected sooner or later and is then lost forever. You must rebase the main repository to refer to the updated submodule commit. Otherwise, you risk that the main repository's history references a commit that is unavailable. You can also just make a new commit in the main repository that updates the submodule reference, but then you still have the invalid submodule reference in the history. This may bother you, or it may not, it's your draw.

Comment: @j6t Thanks! Your comment confirms and alignes with what I thought. Looks like there is no quick direct way to do this for us as provided by git cli. If one aims for automated solution on this, I would see it as complicated although not impossible. Maybe utilize `git filter-branch` then feed it will script to check validity of each commit (is there parent comit?, still reachable?, etc) then query against updated submodule repository for particular commit title/message to acquire an updated commit hash. But again, title/message might change. Complicated. Thanks again for confirmation on this!

Comment: An alternative is, of course, to not let the original submodule commit get lost. You can tack a tag on it, perhaps with a notice that it is "only to keep this commit alive because it is referenced from somewhere else."